# If a particular piece of material has a finite conductivity, then does having the same material of infinite width guarantee infinite conductivity?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, conductors

I'm just wondering if the total conductivity of something will tend to infinity if the material of the thing tends to infinite area. For example, will theoretically a capacitor be a short circuit if its dielectric material has finite conductivity but the width of the capacitor is infinite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you try to stretch things out to infinity, equations break.

You are correct that, if you have an infinitely large cross sectional area of a conductor, its conductivity will be infinite.  However, to realize that infinite conductivity, you also need to connect to this conductor on an infinitely large cross section.  If you had an infinite cross section piece of copper, and connected an alligator clip to one side and an alligator clip to the other, you'd find that some of the electricity gets to go straight through the middle.  Some has to take a longer path around the middle, to leverage the conductivity of the stuff that's further from the center.  Some has to take an infinitely long path to travel from the center of this conductor (where you put the alligator clips) to the edges.  Obviously these infinite paths have infinite resistance.  Which infinity overwhelms the other is really a matter of topology, but I believe the answer is that you never see infinite conductivity.

You will also see the equations break down due to transmission delays.  If you put a signal into your infinite capacitor, it will take an infinitely long time for the signal to propagate to the furthest edges of your plate.

An amusing example of this appears in [an old Google interview question](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath668/kmath668.htm).  It asks, if given an infinite grid of 1 ohm resistors, what is the resistance between two nodes which are separated by a knight move (two moves up, one move over).  While a grid of resistors is not quite the infinite capacitor you mention, it is an example of where you do not see infinite conductivity just because there are infinite paths.